# Fix swing raw type usage in Java 7

Tags: java, swing, generics, java-7

I'm going through some old code that throws warnings now that we're using Java 7.  I have the following method, which produces a number of type safety warnings in Eclipse.  In most cases, the resolution has been fairly straightforward, but the default eclipse fix for the problem results in compilation errors.

```
 public static JList list(ListModel listModel, ListCellRenderer cellRenderer) {
    JList list = new JList();
    if (cellRenderer != null) {
        list.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
    }
    else {
        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomeListCellRenderer());
    }
    list.setModel(listModel);
    if (listModel != null) {
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Eclipse changes this to:

```
public static JList<?> list(ListModel<?> listModel, ListCellRenderer<?> cellRenderer) {
    JList<?> list = new JList<Object>();
    if (cellRenderer != null) {
        list.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
    }
    else {
        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomeListCellRenderer());
    }
    list.setModel(listModel);
    if (listModel != null) {
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This causes the errors:

```
The method setCellRenderer(ListCellRenderer<? super capture#4-of ?>) in the type JList<capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (ListCellRenderer<capture#5-of?>)
```

and

```
The method setModel(ListModel<capture#7-of ?>) in the type JList<capture#7-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (ListModel<capture#8-of ?>)
```

I feel like I don't quite understand generics well enough to figure out what is causing this.  I tried changing a number of the type arguments from ? to Object, which resolves the compilation errors but I don't actually want to return JList of type Object.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Edit:
I genericized the whole method to the following:

```
public static <T> JList<T> list(ListModel<T> listModel, ListCellRenderer<T> cellRenderer) {
    JList<T> list = new JList<T>();
    if (cellRenderer != null) {
        list.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
    }
    else {
        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomeListCellRenderer());
    }
    list.setModel(listModel);
    if (listModel != null) {
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Does this seem like the appropriate way to update the method?

Comment: never heard about open to extension close to modification? .. `JList<?> list = new JList<Object>();` this line i don't like,  i always use T instead of ? in declaration

Comment: Yeah, you're right nachokk, kind of weird.  I just updated the method above with a potential revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
public static <E> JList<E> list(ListModel<E> listModel, ListCellRenderer<? super E> cellRenderer) {
    JList<E> list = new JList<>();
    if (cellRenderer != null) {
        list.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
    }
    else {
        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomeListCellRenderer());
    }
    list.setModel(listModel);
    if (listModel != null) {
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Puce.  That looks like what I need.  What does the empty type JList instantiation do?

Comment: It's an abbreviation, some syntactic sugar added to Java SE 7. It just matches the types of the LHS. Since it looks like diamond, it's often referred to as "diamond operator". http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html